# How we can add column in sql server with auto generated record insertion number. if Index are defined on that table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-administration

My database(SQL server 2008) already having some records and having two sorting index on two columns. I tried to add identity column using following query. But it providing me wrong identity numbers associated with records.

```
alter table Table_name add RECORD_NUMBER int identity(1,1)
```

record which inserted first having higher number and record which is inserted last having lower number. and some records are having just opposite numbers. Is it possible to remove such kind of problem and insert right insertion order for records.

I did this because i was not having any primary key or unique or compost key in my table. So to identify which record is first entered, i introduce identity column. I was thinking that it will allocate record number according to insertion order.

Comment: is there a clustered index on the table? Or a column where you can sort from oldest to newest?

Comment: yes there is index
    CREATE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON TABLE_NAME
    (FIELD_NAME
    )

Comment: keep in mind: data are only sorted after this column if it's a CLUSTERED index! what if you order by the column in the index? do you get data in correct order (from oldest to newest / newst to oldest)?

Comment: yes, if i am doing that then i am getting right order for records. but identity column are not getting right value.

Comment: do you have to alter the existing table or is it possible for you to create a new one (which has the same name and all data afterwards)?

Comment: If you care about the numeric value of an identity column, you're *using them wrongly*. You should treat them as opaque blobs that happen to fit in `int` columns. And tables are, generally, considered to be an *unordered* set of rows.

Comment: you are right @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I think what Vinay Sharma wants is kind of abuse of an identiy column as it should indicate in which order data were added to the table. This should happen with a Timestamp coumn instead for example. But if a table has a clustered index, then it's no longer unordered set as data are physically stored ordered by the column(s) in clustered index.

Comment: @CeOnSql - the only thing you should care about when it comes to the clustered index is that range queries on the clustered index should be cheaper than any other range queries. The pages are *logically* ordered based on it but may be physically located out of order. Rows within pages may appear out of order also (whilst being indexed within the page in the correct logical order).

Comment: yes correct, that's an interesting topic anyway! it's not reliable but for this problem it should work (hopefully). as he mentioned below ("main problem is that i am not having any unique column in my database") --> that's a really bad situation ;-)

Comment: Please mark it like so we can get more answers.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever would you like to share how we can handle this type of problem. As i have already mentioned that i am not having any unique or compost key in my table.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible for you to move data in a new table then this is an approach which is basically recommended by Microsoft:

```
/*************

Preparing for the example, create tables, insert sample data,...

**************/
-- Your existing table
CREATE TABLE dbo.oldtable
(
    colA int,
    colB nvarchar(10)
)

-- The new table, same structure + new identity column:
CREATE TABLE dbo.newtable
(
    colID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    colA int,
    colB nvarchar(10)
)

--create unique clustered index on new identity column
create unique clustered index ucx_newtable 
on dbo.newtable (colID ASC)

--create other indexes as you need them
create index idx_newtable
on dbo.newtable (colA ASC)

--sample data
insert into dbo.oldtable(colA,colB) 
values (16,'this'),(17,'is'),(225,'an'),(300,'example')


/*************

Data Movement

**************/


BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
    --move data to new table including new id column which is generated by
    --colA, which gives us the order from old to new in this example

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.newtable ON --So we can insert into the colID identity column

    INSERT INTO dbo.newtable(colID, colA,colB)
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY colA ASC) AS colID --this will generate numbers beginning from 1
            ,colA, colB
    FROM    dbo.oldtable

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.newtable OFF

    --rename old table / or drop it if you want
    EXEC sp_rename @objname = 'dbo.oldtable', @newname = 'dbo.oldtable_xyz'
    EXEC sp_rename @objname = 'dbo.newtable', @newname = 'dbo.oldtable'

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: main problem is that i am not having any unique column in my database.

Comment: sorry, my mistake! columnA does not have to be unique - it only hast to be the column to order data! answer editet!